# Does Firebase Job dispatcher needs internet access for scheduling job?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-job-dispatcher

Does Firebase Job dispatcher needs Internet access for scheduling job?
When I turn off my Internet access it seems like the scheduled job is not doing anything at all. When I turn it on back, the scheduled job starts the working.

This my code for scheduling job using Firebase Job.

```
FirebaseJobDispatcher dispatcher = 
                    new FirebaseJobDispatcher(new GooglePlayDriver(this));
Job myJob = dispatcher.newJobBuilder()
   .setService(MyJobService.class)
   .setRecurring(true)
   .setTrigger(Trigger.executionWindow(2, 10))
   .setRetryStrategy(RetryStrategy.DEFAULT_LINEAR)
   .setTag("location-update-job")
   .setLifetime(Lifetime.FOREVER)
   .setConstraints(Constraint.ON_ANY_NETWORK)
   .setRecurring(true)
   .build();

dispatcher.mustSchedule(myJob);
```

Comment: if you want remove .setRecurring(true), it is entered  twice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

when you use `.setConstraints(Constraint.ON_ANY_NETWORK)` the job will be executed when there is any type of network connection, You can choose between none, any and unmetered (Wifi), by default it's `NONE` so just delete the `setConstraints`

Comment: Thank you for the right solution. This was the answer that I was looking for.

Comment: if the Internet is not available, and i have select Constraint.ON_ANY_NETWORK, will the job be executed? or it will be executed only when internet is available?

Comment: it will not be executed and once you are connected the first job will run